# How can I give someone a role when they join a specific voice channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am a beginner so don't hate me.
I am trying to give someone a role when they join a specific voice channel.

Here is my code:

````
import discord
from discord import Member, Guild

client = discord.Client()

#########################################################################

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Hello!'.format(client.user.name))

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after ):
    role = discord.utils.get(after.server.roles, name="Talk-1")
    if not before.voice.voice_channel and after.voice.voice_channel:
        await client.add_roles(after, role)
    elif before.voice.voice_channel and not after.voice.voice_channel:
        await client.remove_roles(after, role)

client.run('My Token')```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were heading in the right direction. You only need to define the ID of the specific voice channel and then check if `after.channel.id` is equal to that. Also make sure to use `member.add_roles` instead of `client.add_roles`. So something like this should work:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(after.server.roles, name="Talk-1")
    channel_id = 123456

    if before.channel is None or before.channel.id != voice_channel:
        if after.channel is not None and after.channel.id == voice_channel:
            await member.add_roles(vc_role)

    #reversed from above
    if after.channel is None or after.channel.id != voice_channel:
        if before.channel is not None and before.channel.id == voice_channel:
            await member.remove_roles(vc_role)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=voice%20state%20update#discord.on_voice_state_update